# Is the ip address of a website resolved by the browser or the O/S?

Tags: browser, dns

When you type in an address such as www.google.com, the http request that gets sent out to is
173.194.75.147 port:80.

Two questions

1>Is it the browser or the OS that contacts the DNS service to resolve 173.194.75.147?

2> Does the browser know to target port 80 by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser lets the OS do the name-lookup. For example, in Windows 7, the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file is queried first, then DNS servers. In Linux, FreeBSD etc, `/etc/hosts` is queried first, then the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Destination-port=80 is the default when your URL targets the http protocol, destination-port=443 when the protocol is https etc. This is "decided" by your browser, according to standards.

Answer (score 2):

Queries are run by the inet service that is run by the operation system.  Hosts CAN be set up to be queried first, then DNS servers but not ALWAYS.  On UNIX servers the /etc/nsswitch.conf file defines the order of resolution.

The browser is set to query on port 80 by default.  You can modify this by placing a ':' and another number after the complete URL to modify the behavior.

You can do your own DNS resolutions with the `nslookup` command.

To see simialr behavior at a 'lower' level, play with cURL a bit on the command line.  You'll see that URL's are resolved without the use of the browser.  You'll also see port 80 used by default with HTTP requests.